# call a list of telephonenumbers and go back to the activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, call, bundle

I want to call some numbers inside of an array. So I put them in a Loop and started with an intent the call app. With the phonecalllistener I go back to my activity when the call is finished but my problem is that the loop starts again from begin and I have to click the button again.

Can I solve this Problem with a Bundle? And How?
How can I save my loopstate when the activity is restarting?

I also have written the right permissions in the manifest(CALL_PHONE and READ_PHONE_STATE)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;

private Button button;
public int g = 0;
public String[] nummern = new String[10];


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
    nummern[0] = "tel:06746468156";
    nummern[1] = "tel:06991046460";
    nummern[2] = "tel:06504146464";

    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                for (g = 0; g <= nummern.length-1; g++) {

                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(nummern[g]));
                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }


        }

    });

}

private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";


    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended,
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Juste save your loop state, or which phone number have been called

Comment: How can I save my loopstate when the activity is restarting?

Comment: If i'm understanding your code right, you restart the app after the call finishes ? why do you do this ? You could just call the next number from there, instead of restarting the app

Answer (score 0):

From your button click listener, call startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode) with first number should be passed as intent data,once call is completed  "onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)" method will be called and from this  method you can start the activity again.You can apply the logic accordingly.